# Property 'tableName' does not exist on type 'Model'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class

I'm trying to convert a javascript code to typescript.
I have a class which used to work properly in js

```js
class Model {

    constructor(input, alias) {
        this.tableName = input;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

but now I get two errors saying `Property 'tableName' does not exist on type 'Model'` and `Property 'alias' does not exist on type 'Model'`

also this is my tsconfig settings :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "target": "ES6",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "strict": false,
      "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "include": ["controllers", "models", "module","routes","./app.ts"],
    "ts-node": {
      "transpileOnly": true
    }
  }
```

I'm kinda new to typescript and don't know much about it.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the property

```
class Model {
    tableName:string;
    alias:string;
    constructor(input, alias) {
        this.tableName = input;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html